# If the matrix $A \in K^{m \times n}$ has $m$ pivots and the matrix $B \in K^{n \times r}$ has $n$ pivots, does the matrix $AB$ has $m$ pivots?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ matrices such that $A \in K^{m \times n}$ and $B \in K^{n \times r}$ with $A$ having $m$ pivots, and $B$ having $n$ pivots $(m \le n \le r)$.

Prove that the matrix $AB$ has $m$ pivots.

How can I prove this with elementary theory of matrices?

Comment: To confirm, $A$ has $m$ rows and $K$ has $n$ rows, so are we assuming $A$ is square (but not necessarily $B$)?

Comment: @TheoBendit $A$ has $m$ rows but not square, and $B$ has $n$ rows but not square

Comment: So how can they have the same number of rows if $m \neq n$?

Comment: @TheoBendit I edited the post, I wasn't clear with my redaction

Comment: Ah. I think you mean "same number of pivots **as** rows". It might be a good idea to edit the title to reflect this. Also, a couple of observations, this requires the two matrices to have at least as many columns as rows (i.e. $m \le n \le r$), and under this condition, having pivots in every row is also known as having full rank (or full row-rank).

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks, I just edited the post

Answer (score 2):

A matrix $A$ has the same number of pivots as rows (or perhaps more simply, has a pivot in every row) if and only if the equation $Ax=y$ has a solution for every $y$.  To see that this is true, just think about how you use echelon forms to solve linear equations.

So, suppose this is true for $A$ and also for $B$.  We need to prove that it is true for $AB$.  For any $y$ there exists $z$ such that $Az=y$; then there exists $x$ such that $Bx=z$; and so $ABx=y$.  Thus $ABx=y$ has a solution for every $y$, and so $AB$ has the same number of pivots as rows.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear; $A$ must have the same numbers of pivots and rows and also $B$, by separate

Comment: Have given a new answer to suit the revised question.